# CNN 1D for time series. Value Error. I did read all the possible answers in StackOverflow regardiing this problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, cnn

I been fighting with this problem for 2 weeks now. And I extensively research for solutions here and in other sites.
I have a dataset of 4 dimensions device_id, time and longitude and latitude.
After preprocessing it look like this i got this shape

```
data1.shape
(95751, 4)

data1cnn2 = data1.values.reshape(1,95751, 4)

data1cnn2.shape

(1, 95751, 4)

y.shape

(95751,)

Then this is the code for the CNN1d . using Tensor-flow

modelcnn = Sequential()
modelcnn.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', input_shape=(95751, 4)))
modelcnn.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
modelcnn.add(Flatten())
modelcnn.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
modelcnn.add(Dense(1))
modelcnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

then I fit the model

```
modelcnn.fit(data2cnn, y, epochs=1000, verbose=0)
```

and I get this mistake

```
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 95751 target samples.

modelcnn.summary()

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 95750, 64)         576       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1 (None, 47875, 64)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 3064000)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 50)                153200050 
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 51        
=================================================================
Total params: 153,200,677
Trainable params: 153,200,677
Non-trainable params: 0
_
```

I also try with different solution but got different type of mistakes

I did

```
data1cnn = data1.values.reshape(95751, 4,1)

data1cnn.shape
(95751, 4, 1)
```

but i got this other mistake

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_2_input to have shape (95751, 4) but got array with shape (4, 1)

modelcnn.summary()
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 95750, 64)         576       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1 (None, 47875, 64)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 3064000)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 50)                153200050 
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 51        
=================================================================
Total params: 153,200,677
Trainable params: 153,200,677
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I am completely stuck and I have read all the question and answers that are here . With no success

Answer (score 1):

Your first error is because Keras wants the batch size as first dimension. Given that your Y has 95751 observations, your X must be reshaped in order to have 95751 records in the first dimension, as you did in the second part.

The code doesn't work because Keras has already put the first dimension (None = batch_size) for you (see `model.summary()`), so you don't need to specify that in `input_shape`. You need to change this

```
input_shape=(95751, 4)
```

into this

```
input_shape=(4, 1)
```

**Update after comment - working example**

Here's a working example of your code.

First I define X and Y following your shapes. Here I use random numbers given that I don't have your data

```
data1cnn = np.random.rand(95751, 4, 1)
y = np.random.rand(95751,)
```

I check the shapes to be sure that they are the same as the ones you have provided in your second part of the question

```
print('X and Y shape')
print(data1cnn.shape, y.shape)
```

Output

```
X and Y shape
(95751, 4, 1) (95751,)
```

Looks correct. Now I define the model: everything is the same as in your code but `input_shape=(4, 1)`

```
modelcnn = Sequential()
modelcnn.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', 
input_shape=(4, 1)))
modelcnn.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
modelcnn.add(Flatten())
modelcnn.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
modelcnn.add(Dense(1))
modelcnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

I print the summary

```
print('Model summary')
print(modelcnn.summary())
```

Output

```
Model summary
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)           (None, 3, 64)             192       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling (None, 1, 64)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)         (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 50)                3250      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 51        
=================================================================
Total params: 3,493
Trainable params: 3,493
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Then I train it using the same command you wrote in your question but `verbose=1` to print some information during training

```
modelcnn.fit(data1cnn, y, epochs=1000, verbose=1)
```

and it trains without a problem given that I get as output

```
Epoch 1/1000
95751/95751 [==============================] - 6s 60us/step - loss: 0.0844
Epoch 2/1000
95751/95751 [==============================] - 7s 76us/step - loss: 0.0833
Epoch 3/1000
95751/95751 [==============================] - 6s 59us/step - loss: 0.0832
Epoch 4/1000
95751/95751 [==============================] - 6s 66us/step - loss: 0.0831
Epoch 5/1000
95751/95751 [==============================] - 5s 54us/step - loss: 0.0831
Epoch 6/1000
95751/95751 [==============================] - 5s 54us/step - loss: 0.0830
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I have done as you said and I still got  error:
```
modelcnn.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', input_shape=(4,1)))

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)
```
i have no enough space to add the model summary()

Comment: I can't help you without having a look at what you are doing. I put a working example in my answer following your description of the problem. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you.
I have a very similar problem with an LSTM
I will post tomorrow the question and send to you the link here

Comment: I work by the way